Is Latin "futuo" the Progenitor of English "fuck"?
English swear word "fuck" is in such widespread use, some use it as a punctuation mark, that it's study must be valid, however unpleasant.  I've grown up, here, in England, believing that "fuck" is an Anglo-Saxon term. A (possible) Germanic origin is mentioned in the Wiki article, "Fuck"--well-worth a read. The trouble with this theory is that Anglo-Saxon swear-words were not written down. The only people who could write, then, scribes & monks, did not colour their beautifully illustrated manuscripts with expletives, obviously. Therefore, how does anyone know what these words were? The Oxford entry for "fuck" ends [16th c.; orig. unkn.].
What is clear is the "FU" root in both "fuck" and Latin verb "futuo". After four centuries of Roman occupation and with approx. half the words in English being Latin, or Latin-derived (or from Norman French--a Romance language), could not "fuck" have a Latin origin?
Similar terms in other Germanic languages do not always mean sexual intercourse (Wiki article). Latin, "futuo" does mean sexual penetration; though, not for being penetrated. Enough, perhaps, to provide the required linguistic evolution.
I do not expect a definitive answer on this, there probably isn't one; but, any thoughts?
EDIT 29/12/2024:
Thanks to Joonas who has recommended PIE theory for the (possible) German origin of "fuck". This Anglo-Saxon thing has been mentioned, above. The Germanic origin seems to have credibility because of similar words occurring in Germanic languages, which align with PIE roots e.g. German "ficken" = "to fuck";  Dutch "fokken" = "to breed";  Afrikaans "fok" = "to fuck" (Wiki article, cited above).
When the Romans and the German tribes were not fighting they interacted; they communicated, presumably in Latin, when it suited. If "fuck" is (is) of German origin it might have been influenced by "futuo". Though Joonas sees a two-letter root as insignificant (What about the "EX" root now manifest in many contemporary [proto-Latin] English words?) for me, the "FU" root between two, near-synonymous, words is worthy of consideration, isn't it?

Did you check the etymologies of "fuck" and "futuere" anywhere? Even just Wiktionary? That'd take you much further than comparing the first two letters.

To clarify, I think it would be better to make the outcome of your initial query more explicit: "according to X the etymology of Y is Z", repeated for both words with links to the relevant entries if available online. That will also allow you to make a reasonable guess on the nature of the relationship. Sharing an initial segment is not a good measure; otherwise one might think that "penguin" and "pension" are closely related with their shared first three letters. I don't mind the topic (some might); I only voted down for unclear background for etymological speculation.

@Joonas llmavirta: Yes, as well as various dictionaries. The words "penguin" & "pension" don't mean the same thing, do they; "fuck" & "futuo" do (almost)? Given that, the common root is therefore to be seen as a coincidence, is it? Unlikely but difficult to prove. Such conjecture could have been the basis of an answer. How is an etymological study to be conducted when Wiki gives a vague Germanic origin, which was never written down; Oxford says "origin unknown"; L&S said very little. The Q. does not require answers that don't exist; it is an invitation for informed speculation.

Wiktionary gives an etymology for both "futuere" and "fuck", tracing them back to different PIE roots. A check like that was what I was trying to ask you to include in your question. The similar initial segments are a coincidence and a well understood one. Of course Wiktionary may have it wrong, but at least it will give an informed guess. Explicit links and quotes would improve the question, and they don't prevent summarizing it in your own words.

Probably not:

While the etymology of "fuck" isn't entirely certain, it lines up very nicely with the well-attested PIE root *pewǵ- via Grimm's Law; this would make it cognate with Latin pugil and pungere instead
Vulgar, low-register words in English almost always come from Anglo-Saxon, not from Latin or French; compare the usage of "shit" versus "feces" and "defecate"
Futuere is attested too early in Latin for the loan to have gone the other way
The change from /t/ to /k/ is hard to explain, since we don't see any variants with /k/ in Latin, or with /t/ in Germanic

As an amusing side note:

The trouble with this theory is that Anglo-Saxon swear-words were not written down. The only people who could write, then, scribes & monks, did not colour their beautifully illustrated manuscripts with expletives, obviously.

You might be surprised to know they absolutely did! One of the earliest instances of the word "fuck" in writing comes from the margin of Brasenose College MS 7 f.62v:

At the bottom of a page of Cicero's Dē Officiīs, a monk scribbled "O d[amn?] fuckin Abbot". From the context, historians have even figured out the identity of this damn fuckin Abbot: the wildly unpopular and hypocritical John Burton. It seems this monk thought his abbot could do to study the moral principles in Dē Officiīs a bit more closely!

Good answer! I'd suggest adding a note on the difference between "root" and "the first few letters", as there seems to be a confusion in the OP.

@Draconis: Thank you. An excellent answer! If a theory is wrong it must be debunked. Another interesting aspect, in the linked article: "At that time 'fuck' was a word used to describe sex. It wasn't a swearword as we'd use it today. So the 'fucking' here is probably being used literally: 'Oh that abbot who fucks a lot.'" The monk, by his own lights, was not using an expletive. This beggars a new question: when did 'fuck' become a swearword?'
